# Is there a documented list of Snowflake query types?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working with the view `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY`.  It would be extremely helpful to have an exhaustive list of query types that might appear in the column **QUERY_TYPE**, with the type of commands that generate them.  For example, does a **PUT** command generate a *PUT query type*?  Or is it something like *"LOAD"*?

If anyone knows where such a list can be found, please post a link.  Snowflake's documentation of the view does not provide any list.

Comment: There is a list located in this page: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html#output, but I will admit that this list doesn't appear to be complete.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks all who have answered so far.  Since the consensus is that no such list exists, here is a merge of the entries provided so far with the values found in my own database.  Please keep posting additional answers if your DB contains entries not found below.  This way, sooner or later, we will have a fairly complete list:

| QUERY_TYPE |
| --- |
| CREATE_USER |
| REVOKE |
| DROP_CONSTRAINT |
| RENAME_SCHEMA |
| UPDATE |
| CREATE_VIEW |
| CREATE_TASK |
| RENAME_TABLE |
| INSERT |
| ALTER_TABLE_ADD_COLUMN |
| RENAME_COLUMN |
| MERGE |
| BEGIN_TRANSACTION |
| ALTER_VIEW_MODIFY_SECURITY |
| GRANT |
| ALTER_SESSION |
| DELETE |
| DROP_ROLE |
| DESCRIBE |
| UNKNOWN |
| TRUNCATE_TABLE |
| DROP |
| SHOW |
| ALTER_WAREHOUSE_SUSPEND |
| GET_FILES |
| UNLOAD |
| CREATE_NETWORK_POLICY |
| ALTER_TABLE_DROP_COLUMN |
| CREATE |
| REMOVE_FILES |
| ALTER |
| ALTER_USER |
| PUT_FILES |
| COPY |
| ALTER_ACCOUNT |
| DROP_TASK |
| CREATE_CONSTRAINT |
| DESCRIBE_QUERY |
| SELECT |
| RENAME_USER |
| COMMIT |
| RENAME_VIEW |
| USE |
| CREATE_TABLE |
| ALTER_NETWORK_POLICY |
| CREATE_ROLE |
| ALTER_TABLE_MODIFY_COLUMN |
| SET |
| ALTER_USER_ABORT_ALL_JOBS |
| ROLLBACK |
| LIST_FILES |
| UNSET |
| CREATE_TABLE_AS_SELECT |
| DROP_USER |
| ALTER_WAREHOUSE_RESUME |
| QUERY_TYPE |
| ALTER_PIPE |
| ALTER_ROLE |
| ALTER_TABLE |
| ALTER_TABLE_DROP_CLUSTERING_KEY |
| ALTER_USER_RESET_PASSWORD |
| CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE |
| CREATE_MASKING_POLICY |
| CREATE_SEQUENCE |
| CREATE_STREAM |
| DROP_STREAM |
| RENAME_DATABASE |
| RENAME_FILE_FORMAT |
| RENAME_ROLE |
| RENAME_WAREHOUSE |
| RESTORE |

Comment: Wonder if Snowflake will take the hint and document this ?

Comment: Can you please order alphabetically?

Comment: Just added a handful in a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

By the looks of it there is no complete list of query types that show up in this table. Best I can do is give you a list from my own database, which still doesn't contain things like `alter role` etc. To answer your other question a `PUT` command is actually `PUT_FILES` by the looks of it:

```sql
select distinct query_type from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY;

+-------------------------+
|QUERY_TYPE               |
+-------------------------+
|ALTER                    |
|ALTER_SESSION            |
|ALTER_TABLE_ADD_COLUMN   |
|ALTER_TABLE_DROP_COLUMN  |
|ALTER_TABLE_MODIFY_COLUMN|
|ALTER_USER               |
|ALTER_WAREHOUSE_RESUME   |
|ALTER_WAREHOUSE_SUSPEND  |
|BEGIN_TRANSACTION        |
|COMMIT                   |
|COPY                     |
|CREATE                   |
|CREATE_CONSTRAINT        |
|CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE    |
|CREATE_MASKING_POLICY    |
|CREATE_ROLE              |
|CREATE_SEQUENCE          |
|CREATE_STREAM            |
|CREATE_TABLE             |
|CREATE_TABLE_AS_SELECT   |
|CREATE_USER              |
|CREATE_VIEW              |
|DELETE                   |
|DESCRIBE                 |
|DESCRIBE_QUERY           |
|DROP                     |
|DROP_CONSTRAINT          |
|DROP_STREAM              |
|DROP_USER                |
|GET_FILES                |
|GRANT                    |
|INSERT                   |
|LIST_FILES               |
|MERGE                    |
|PUT_FILES                |
|REMOVE_FILES             |
|RENAME_COLUMN            |
|RENAME_DATABASE          |
|RENAME_TABLE             |
|RESTORE                  |
|REVOKE                   |
|ROLLBACK                 |
|SELECT                   |
|SET                      |
|SHOW                     |
|TRUNCATE_TABLE           |
|UNKNOWN                  |
|UNLOAD                   |
|UPDATE                   |
|USE                      |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: What's the 'UNKNOWN' ? If you take a peak at the SQL ... also recommend predicating success for status.

Comment: Looks like the 'UNKNOWN' is mostly for failed queries but not all. Here is an example of an 'UNKNOWN' that succeeded: `SELECT * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))`

Answer (score 4):

Added ours ... 16 extra's ... pass it on :-)

```
QUERY_TYPE
ALTER
ALTER_ACCOUNT
ALTER_PIPE
ALTER_ROLE
ALTER_SESSION
ALTER_TABLE
ALTER_TABLE_ADD_COLUMN
ALTER_TABLE_DROP_CLUSTERING_KEY
ALTER_TABLE_DROP_COLUMN
ALTER_TABLE_MODIFY_COLUMN
ALTER_USER
ALTER_USER_ABORT_ALL_JOBS
ALTER_USER_RESET_PASSWORD
ALTER_WAREHOUSE_RESUME
ALTER_WAREHOUSE_SUSPEND
BEGIN_TRANSACTION
COMMIT
COPY
CREATE
CREATE_CONSTRAINT
CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE
CREATE_MASKING_POLICY
CREATE_NETWORK_POLICY
CREATE_ROLE
CREATE_SEQUENCE
CREATE_STREAM
CREATE_TABLE
CREATE_TABLE_AS_SELECT
CREATE_TASK
CREATE_USER
CREATE_VIEW
DELETE
DESCRIBE
DESCRIBE_QUERY
DROP
DROP_CONSTRAINT
DROP_ROLE
DROP_STREAM
DROP_TASK
DROP_USER
GET_FILES
GRANT
INSERT
LIST_FILES
MERGE
PUT_FILES
REMOVE_FILES
RENAME_COLUMN
RENAME_DATABASE
RENAME_FILE_FORMAT
RENAME_ROLE
RENAME_SCHEMA
RENAME_TABLE
RENAME_USER
RENAME_VIEW
RENAME_WAREHOUSE
RESTORE
REVOKE
ROLLBACK
SELECT
SET
SHOW
TRUNCATE_TABLE
UNKNOWN
UNLOAD
UNSET
UPDATE
USE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some additional ones:

```sql
ALTER_AUTO_RECLUSTER
ALTER_SET_TAG
ALTER_TABLE_MODIFY_CONSTRAINT
ALTER_UNSET_TAG
CALL
DROP_SESSION_POLICY
RECLUSTER
```